# Is sketching or drawing someone else's photograph a copyright violation?

Tags: copyright, drawing, sketching

If someone were to sketch or draw (digital or otherwise) an existing photograph by someone else of say, the Pyramids of Giza (by "photograph", I'm referring to images taken with a camera and not other sketches and drawings), would it be a copyright violation if one were to, for example use the sketch or drawing as a background in a poster or incorporate it along with an existing creative that one might be working on?

---

**N.B.** Not sure if this should be posted in [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/), [Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) or here in [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) so if it belongs somewhere else, do kindly migrate it to the relevant community (or let me know and I'll delete and post it in the correct community).

Comment: Yes, it's a copyright infringement.

Comment: It’s not clear whether “someone” and “one” in your question are meant to be the same person. Did _you_ sketch the pyramid from the photo and then use it in a poster? Or did someone else sketch it and then you use it in a poster? And is the sketch an exact replication of the photo, or just a loose interpretation drawing inspiration from it?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I’m voting to close this question because it's a legal question. Sorry about that. Please don't ask for legal advice here. It's off-topic.  Also note, I don't think Law Stack Exchange gives free legal advice, just like we don't give away free designs.

Comment: @BillyKerr im not sure this is offtopic per see. Anyway copyright does not care if ors based of somebody elses work it is based on somebody elses work.

Comment: @BillyKerr Understandable. Is there a specific Stack Exchange community that a question like this would most probably be relevant in. Regards.

Comment: @joojaa That makes sense. Thanks for the pointer. Fwiw, I'm not really a designer but a programmer and was just wondering about this earlier.

Comment: @joojaa - I'm honestly not comfortable answering legal questions at all. I'm just not qualified to do that. But I agree with you that we should assume all photographs are copyright (unless it has expired or has a CC licence), and copying them in any way is infringement.

Comment: @AndrewL64 - run it by your lawyer instead.

Comment: @janusbahsjacquet someone and one would be the same person in the above hypothetical scenario yes. And would an exact sketch replica and a loose interpretation in sketch be looked upon differently from a copyright point of view?

Comment: @AndrewL64 Generally, yes. If you draw a loose interpretation of an existing artwork, then you’re _creating_ a separate artwork; finding inspiration in existing art is not copyright infringement. If you set out to make an exact copy, though, you’re not creating anything new, just _copying_ something – which is exactly what you have to hold the copyright to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One needs to clarify the usage and *intent*....

If you merely **look at** a photograph and draw based on *what you see*, there's rarely any infringement. Using **reference** is exceptionally common and almost mandatory at times. I mean, there's no way I can travel to Giza to *personally* look at the pyramids in order to draw them. There's no way I could travel the south pole to view penguins in their natural habitat. [Extreme example: There's no way I can cut open a cadaver to view the internal organs of a human.] I would need to use photographs as reference..... etc.

However, if one uses a photograph as a *tracing basis* - meaning you use some automated or manual method to directly mimic the object(s) within the photograph, then **yes** it is *often* infringement or at a minimum [derivative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) ([2](https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/what-are-derivative-works-under-copyright-law)). This **includes** things like painting over a photograph in Photoshop. Or using Illustrator to place the photograph as a template for drawing on top of, etc.. A vector recreation of a raster image **is** derivative at best and most often **is** an infringement.

---

Typically using a photograph as *reference* won't yield any direct representative copy of that photograph and if one is using a photo as *reference* there's rarely a desire to replicate the photo as close as possible. But even if drawing by hand, if you are so adept that you mimic a photo exactly, that too may be infringement.

There are often some major legal battles surrounding photos as reference. [One such case can be read about here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama_%22Hope%22_poster). And as explained, it really depends upon *how* a photograph is used and the resulting artwork created.

---

Ultimately, what is or is not an infringement can **only** be definitively determined by viewing the original photograph and the subsequent artwork created. It's all art, *not* science so there's no "formula" or "acceptable limit". So until actual work is viewed everything is merely speculation.

Be aware... you'll **often** see or hear people state "as long as you change it by X%, it's okay". This is entirely **false**. There's no such claus or loophole in any copyright law.

In *most* instances... if you question whether or not you are infringing up the rights of someone else, you *probably* already know the answer.

Comment: `I mean, there's no way I can travel to Giza to personally look at the pyramids in order to draw them. There's no way I could travel the south pole to view penguins in their natural habitat.` haha good point. And as much as I agree with you with regards to `if you are so adept that you mimic a photo exactly, that too may be infringement.`, it seems a bit ambiguous that a copyright infringement might depend on how good a drawer/sketcher/painter is imo.

Comment: @AndrewL64 it *is* a bit ambiguous. Infringement can really only be *definitively* decided by viewing the original photograph and the resulting creation. **Intent** plays a large part. That's why there are legal battles - a difference in the interpretation of the ambiguity. It's **art** not science. `:)`

Comment: Also, interestingly, I did a quick google search about tracing just now and it seems there are people online who claim that tracing copyrighted images is not exactly illegal apparently. Not sure how legit that claim is though.

Comment: @AndrewL64 -- `:)` -- So, you're saying if it's on the internet it's true?? `:)` -- There are people who will *claim* practically anything with respect to Intellectual Property is legal. Mostly because it serves their *own personal interests*. Not because it's a valid statement. If all you do is trace photos in Illustrator, *of course* you are going to claim it's *not* infringement.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it all comes down to intent indeed. Apparently, according to an *Art and Entertainment Attorney* in some thread in Quora, there is an exception with regards to certain situations (Fair use) where it is a way of saying that certain kinds of speech (or material I guess), that would otherwise constitute copyright infringement, are more important than the rights of authors. But that is really vague and again, ambiguous.

Comment: @AndrewL64 yes Fair Use exists and is a real thing. But.. if you are selling, or profiting off of infringements, Fair Use goes right out the window. You'll need to read up on Fair Use. It's often not as broad and sweeping as people think it is.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of say, sketching a picture of the pyramids by looking at a photo taken by someone else and uploading it in behance or something where people can use it (no buying/selling involved).

Comment: @AndrewL64 as I posted.. if all you are doing is **looking** at a photograph, most often it's fine.. reference is reference. With reference you won't get every little crack, angle, line, shadow, highlight, etc the same as the photograph.. and if the goal is to get those the same.. why bother? Use a photo is you are simply trying to replicate a photo.

Comment: Agreed. The only thing I'm still unclear with is the ambiguity of the infringement depending on how good the sketcher/drawer/painter is but that is something that might play out differently in different situations depending on the judge, jury and executioner I guess. `*shrugs*`

Comment: "Executioner" lol, relax.  Regarding the quality of the drawing, it must in the end depend on some case-by-case assessment. A poor copy of a photo of a face might just look like a general wiggly smiley face where a top notch artist might be able to make a drawing which can hardly be distinguished from the original. I also believe it matters how unique the original was from the beginning. For example imagine a photo of a red ball on a white background. Very hard to enforce your copyright to such an image.

Comment: Don't go stealing my red ball, @Wolff !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Relevant : https://waxy.org/2011/06/kind_of_screwed/

Comment: @curious That was a good read and I really enjoyed reading that. Kind of cleared up a lot of doubts that I have too. Thank you.